# actionscript 3.0 drag and swap

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is my code for dragging and dropping movie clips into their matching movie clip targets. I would like to make a jigsaw puzzle game where all the pieces are in some place, and when one piece is dragged onto another, they two pieces swap and if the piece matches the target it should lock into place and stay there with this code. Only problem is I don't know how to make the pieces swap locations. Any ideas?? Is this even possible?? Please help...

```
function pickupObject(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.startDrag(true);
    event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
    objectoriginalX=event.target.x;
    objectoriginalY=event.target.y;
}

function dropObject(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.stopDrag();
    var matchingTargetName:String="target"+ event.target.name;
    var matchingTarget:DisplayObject=getChildByName(matchingTargetName);
    if(event.target.dropTarget != null && event.target.dropTarget.parent==matchingTarget)   {
        event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
        event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
        event.target.buttonMode=false;
        event.target.x=matchingTarget.x;
        event.target.y=matchingTarget.y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `event.target` is what you think it is?   `event.currentTarget` will always be the item you attached the listener to,  `event.target` can be any clickable child within that current target.

Comment: I can't say for sure that I do, I don't really know much about this stuff because I'm just getting started but this coding was for a simple drag and drop shape game where you drag the shapes into their correct targets, so that is the context of it. There is other coding that was used for the shapes and I assume I will have to put that in somewhere but I'll try the array coding and see where that takes me :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Store drag and drop objects in two different arrays and x and y positions also. Consider 3 drag and drop objects.

   ```
   var drag:Array = new Array(drag0, drag1, drag2);
   var drop:Array = new Array(drag0_target, drag1_target, drag2_target);
   var points:Array = new Array({x:drag_0.x, y:drag_0.y},...);

   //this regular expression will return a digit number from given string.
   var pattern:RegExp = /\d/;
   ```

*note: drop array object names should be start with drag object names. For matching purpose*.

2. Add `mouse listeners` to the drag array objects.
3. MouseDownHandler()

   `e.target.startDrag();`
4. MouseUpHandler()

   ```
   //create a tmp variable for store the current drag object number;
   tmp = e.target.name.match(pattern);
   for(i=0;i<drop.length; i++){
       //Check whether the hit occurred in the drop clips                  
       if(MovieClip(e.target).hitTestObject(this.drop[i])){
          //Check whether the object has been dropped in a right place.
          if(drop[i].name.split("_")[0] == e.target.name){               
              e.target.x = drop[i].x;
              e.target.y = drop[i].y;
          }else{
              //else place the drag object into the initial position.
              e.target.x = points[tmp].x;
              e.target.y = points[tmp].y;
          }                                             
       }                   
   }
   ```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks so much, I will try this out and see how it goes! :)